# symmetric equality when making a sanitized string type (using scala.Proxy)

Tags: scala

I have a scala (2.10.4) application where email addresses are passed around a lot, and I'd like to implement an abstraction that's called at IO to "sanitize" already validated email addresses.

Using `scala.Proxy` is almost what I want, but I'm running into issues with asymmetric equality.

```
    class SanitizedEmailAddress(s: String) extends Proxy with Ordered[SanitizedEmailAddress] {
  val self: String = s.toLowerCase.trim

  def compare(that: SanitizedEmailAddress) = self compareTo that.self
}

object SanitizedEmailAddress {
  def apply(s: String) = new SanitizedEmailAddress(s)
  implicit def sanitize(s: String): SanitizedEmailAddress = new SanitizedEmailAddress(s)
  implicit def underlying(e: SanitizedEmailAddress): String = e.self
}
```

I'd like to have

```
val sanitizedEmail = SanitizedEmailAddress("Blah@Blah.com")
val expected = "blah@blah.com"
assert(sanitizedEmail == expected) // => true
assert(expected == sanitizedEmail) // => true, but this currently returns false :(
```

Or something with similar functionality. Is there any non-cumbersome way to do this?

```
    assert(sanitizedEmail.self == expected) // => true (but pretty bad, and someone will forget)
// can have a custom equality method and use the "pimp-my-lib" pattern on strings, but then we have to remember to use that method every time
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's possible, sorry.

I'm not sure it's quite right to want that, either. If a `String` is truly equal to a `SanitizedEmailAddress`, then what does the `SanitizedEmailAddress` wrapper actually denote?

I think it would be more consistent to have `String` not comparable to a `SanitizedEmailAddress`, and require users to "sanitize" input before comparing it.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use a marker trait to denote strings that conform.

A function that takes an `Email` string knows that the string is correct.

If an ordinary string compares equal to an `Email` string, then it must also be correct.

```
package object email {
  type Tagged[U] = { type Tag = U }
  type @@[T, U] = T with Tagged[U]
  def smartly[A](s: String): String @@ A = Email(s).asInstanceOf[String @@ A]
}

package email {
  trait Email extends Any
  object Email {
    def apply(s: String) = s.toLowerCase.trim
  }
  object Test extends App {
    def f(ok: String @@ Email) = {
      assert(ok.forall(c => !c.isLetter || c.isLower))
    }
    val x = smartly[Email]("Joe@ACME.com")

    println(x)
    f(x)
    assert("joe@acme.com" == x)
/*
    f("Junk@Yahoo.com")  // DNC
email.scala:22: error: type mismatch;
 found   : String("Junk@Yahoo.com")
 required: email.@@[String,email.Email]
    (which expands to)  String with AnyRef{type Tag = email.Email}
    f("Junk@Yahoo.com")
      ^
one error found
*/
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @som-snytt, I only study your solution in depth after posting my workaround ;-)   Using Tagged type is good, but again given legacy code which pass around email as `String`, the tag info will be lost lower into the call tree.  Take your code as example, `def legacyCode(email: String): Boolean = email.isInstanceOf[Email]` will always return false

Comment: typo, should be: ... `def legacyCode(email: String): Boolean = email.isInstanceOf[String @ Email]` will always return false

Answer (score 1):

What about keeping all email type as String and pimp the 'sanitized' info implicitly:

```
object SanitizedEmailAddress {
  def apply(s: String): String = synchronized {
    val verified = s.toLowerCase.trim
    sanitized.update(verified, true)
    verified
  }

  def isSanitized(s: String): Boolean = synchronized {
    sanitized.contains(s)
  }

  private val sanitized = scala.collection.mutable.WeakHashMap.empty[String, Boolean]
}

implicit class emailOps(val email: String) extends AnyVal {
  def isSanitized: Boolean = SanitizedEmailAddress.isSanitized(email)
}
```

And now:

```
val sanitizedEmail = SanitizedEmailAddress("Blah@Blah.com")
val expected = "blah@blah.com"
assert(sanitizedEmail == expected) // => true
assert(expected == sanitizedEmail) // => true

assert(sanitizedEmail.isSanitized == true) // => true
assert("blah@blah.com".isSanitized == true) // => true
assert("Blah@Blah.com".isSanitized == false) // => true
```

Comment: Then you'd have to invoke the dynamic test before every usage. You might as well let the type system track what has been sanitized.

Comment: In general, yes.  But if there're legacy code that you cannot change, which seems to be the case here, and you don't want to break existing code, then I think my workaround is more failsafe.  Since the existing type is String, I don't think it's possible to introduce a new type which is fully compatible to String.